# How can i apply condition in form builder while getting data in drop down in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I'm new to symfony 
I have a web controller , In Web controller i get all user's name from UserRepository  where roll is  not Admin. every thing fine with createAction but when  i try to update web data in editAction i get an error like

**The value of type "object" cannot be converted to a valid array key.**

In  createAction  im getting users

```
   $all_users = $em->getRepository('MWANMOBILEBIBundle:User')->allWebUser();

      // var_dump($all_users);

        $user_arr=array();
        foreach ($all_users as $single_user){
            $user_arr[$single_user['id']]=$single_user['username'];

        }

$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('description', 'text')
        ->add('primaryUrl', 'text')
        ->add('testUrl', 'text')
        ->add('notes', 'textarea')
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Web Service'))

        ->add('user', 'choice', array('choices' => $user_arr ))
        ->add('parent', 'choice', array('choices' =>     $user_service,'required' => false,))
        ->add('serverStatus', 'checkbox')
        ->add('statusEmail' ,'email')
        ->add('statusMessage' , 'textarea')
        ->getForm();
```

In createFormBuilder below mentioned line is working fine

```
       ->add('user', 'choice', array('choices' => $user_arr ))
```

But when I'm using in edit action i got an error

**The value of type "object" cannot be converted to a valid array key.**

here is my editAction code

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $web = $em->getRepository('MWANMOBILEBIBundle:Web')->find($id);

       $all_users = $em->getRepository('MWANMOBILEBIBundle:User')->allWebUser();

         var_dump($all_users);

        $user_arr=array();
        foreach ($all_users as $single_user)
        {
            $user_arr[$single_user['id']]=$single_user['username'];
        }



        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($web)

        ->add('description', 'text')
        ->add('primaryUrl', 'text')
        ->add('testUrl', 'text')
        ->add('notes', 'textarea')
        ->add('user', 'choice', array('choices' => $user_arr ))
        //->add('user', 'entity', array('class' => 'MWANMOBILEBIBundle:User',
        //      'property' => 'username',))
        ->add('parent', 'entity', array('class' => 'MWANMOBILEBIBundle:Service', 
              'property' => 'description' ))
        ->add('serverStatus', 'checkbox')
        ->add('statusEmail' ,'email')
        ->add('statusMessage' , 'textarea')
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update Web Service'))
        ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Entity Form field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)
you can perform your queries directly in that without your foreach, and in your Entity, set a __tostring() method to return which value to use when saving in your db

Welcome to Symfony mate :)